# Django Class Based Views not rendering variables in Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm pretty new to Django and already have read a lot about class-based views before coming here. I'm trying to build a one page website, with dynamic blocks that can be written from the Django admin. My problem is that I cannot manage to render variables from my database in my template. Here's what I wrote:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class MyResume(models.Model):
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Resume"
        verbose_name_plural = "My Resume"

    def __str__(self):
        return "My Resume"

class AboutMe(models.Model):
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()
    cover_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="about_me")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "About me"
        verbose_name_plural = "About me"

    def __str__(self):
        return "About me"

class Experience(models.Model):
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pres_content = models.TextField()
    exp_content = HTMLField()
    date_exp = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Experience"
        verbose_name_plural = "Experiences"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Experience"

class ProjectPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()
    project_post_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="projectpost_cover")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Project Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Project Posts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    blogpost_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="blogpost_thumbnail")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Posts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Contact(models.Model):
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    presentation_content = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Contact section text"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import *

class IndexTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) # first, call super get context data
        context['myresume'] = MyResume.objects.all()
        context['aboutme'] = AboutMe.objects.all()
        context['experience'] = Experience.objects.all()
        context['projectpost'] = ProjectPost.objects.all()
        context['blogpost'] = BlogPost.objects.all()
        context['contact'] = Contact.objects.all()
        return context
```

core.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import IndexTemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexTemplateView.as_view()),
]
```

appname.urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and a snippet from my index.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

(...)

<!-- ==================== ABOUT ==================== -->
    <section id="about" class="section">
        <h2 class="title">ABOUT</h2>
        <div class="section-des">
            {{ aboutme.subline }}
        </div>

        <div class="content-670">
            <p>
                {{ aboutme.content }}
            </p>
        </div>

        <img class="about-img block-right" data-jarallax-element="0 -40" src="{{ aboutme.cover_img.url }}" alt="">

(...)

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the variables you've added to your template context are [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#all), not objects. But you're trying to read them as individual objects in your template, which is why it doesn't work. You have two options:

1. Iterate over each queryset in your template:

   ```
   {% for item in aboutme %}
        <h2 class="title">ABOUT</h2>
       {{ item.subline }}
       {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
   ```
2. If you only want to display one of each model, then you need to fix your context method to only return one object, e.g.,

   ```
   context['aboutme'] = AboutMe.objects.first()
   ```

Where here you're just returning the first `AboutMe` object in the database. If you do this, then your existing template logic will work.  How you determine which object to return depends on what your data looks like.

Comment: Spot on, i tested both ways to understand, and i think i got it now. Thanks a lot @solarissmoke ! I'm gonna read more about querysets now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for obj in myresume %}
 <p>{{ obj.subline }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for obj in aboutme %}
 <p>{{ obj.subline }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

you can call your objects in this way in your templates. Also modify str function in models to get the dynamic content.

```
class MyResume(models.Model):
    subline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Resume"
        verbose_name_plural = "My Resume"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sublime
```